# flowplayer in a hidden div

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I'm using a flowplayer.  When I put it in the hidden area below, the player does not work.

```
<div class="hidden" style="display:none">
<div class="flowplayer" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.4167">
<video>
<source src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4">
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Flowplayer is available at the following location:
http://flowplayer.org/download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't.

But you can use a workaround of instead using:

```
visbility:hidden;
height:0px;
```

And then it works fine.

[jsFiddle of a working example (warning: you will need sound)](http://jsfiddle.net/EvgYR/)